# Why do I get "mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid"

Tags: php

Why do I get a "mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid" for the first...

```
$r = mysql_query($q, $connection);
```

In the following code...

```
$bId    = trim($_POST['bId']);
$title  = trim($_POST['title']);
$story  = trim($_POST['story']);

$q  = "SELECT * ";
$q .= "FROM " . DB_NAME . ".`blog` ";
$q .= "WHERE `blog`.`id` = {$bId}";
$r = mysql_query($q, $connection);
//confirm_query($r);
if (mysql_num_rows($r) == 1) {      
    $q  = "UPDATE " . DB_NAME . ".`blog` SET
                        `title` = '{$title}',
                        `story` = '{$story}'
                    WHERE `id` = {$bId}";
    $r = mysql_query($q, $connection);
    if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
        //Successful
        $data['success'] = true;
        $date['errors']  = false;
        $date['message'] = "You are the Greatest!";
    } else {
        //Fail
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['error']   = true;
        $date['message'] = "You can't do it fool!";
    }        
}
```

I also get an "mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" error too.

Side notes: I am using 1&1 Hosting (worst hosting ever), custom .htaccess file with one line text to enable PHP 5.2 (only way with 1&1 Hosting).

---

### Extra stuff add after the questions was posted...

Here is how $connection is defined. It is on its own page called connection.php that is called up using the require_once function. It it is called up on every page that require a database connection including the one in question...

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database Connection Failed: </br>" . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Database Selection Failed: </br>" . mysql_error());
    }
```

... I know it is working because this the same connect that I use for the page I have and I have no problems with it. I havent testing on my home server yet, but I am going to later to see if it is related to a 1&1 Hosting issue.

UPDATE: I am in the process of moving from 1&1 Hosting to HostMoster. 1&1 runs a PHP as CGI and runs PHP4 instead of PHP5 (you can make a custom .htaccess file to make it run PHP5). I will update you later.

Comment: Looks sql-injection vulnerable.  Escape your parameters with mysql_real_escape_string() or use parameterized queries.

Comment: I did... You don't see it here because I striped it from here so that I can make it simply to read. I have a function that automatically check to see if "mysql_real_escape_string" is valid. If it is valid then it will check for "get_magic_quotes_gpc" is active. If so, then it will strip the slashes and use "get_magic_quotes_gpc". If not then it will just use "get_magic_quotes_gpc." Finally if get_magic_quotes_gpc and $magic_quotes_active are not valid or enable then it will just add slashes. I got the function from Kevin Shoglund, author of a few videos at Lynda.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first would be because it's not a connection, and the second would be because it's not a query result because it wasn't a connection. Use [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to figure out what went wrong in the connection.

Comment: You might be right because some of my other user defined functions weren't working neither. I stripped them before I posted code. 

Can you connect another page, like functions.php, with require_once() function when using jQuery AJAX? Meaning... one page will ajax post to another page, that requires 4 other pages that have predefined functions, and that page will return data.

Comment: AJAX just initiates another request to the web server. There really isn't all that much different between it and a normal hit from a browser.

Comment: If that is the case then I have defined var $connection. It is the same one I use account all my pages.  At my question, I have add the code to define $connection.

Comment: Your creation of `$connection` is failing. Find out why.

Comment: Look at the above code I have posted. I have no database errors.

Comment: I want to thank you for your help. You kind of confirmed that there wasnt an error my part because I knew there wasnt anything wrong with `$connection`. I moved hosting servers (didnt change any code) and the same script ran like it should. As a bonus if fixed some of the other problems I had. Such as: 1&1 wouldnt allow me to run user defined functions like the one that I had to prevent SQL-Injection and XXS.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `$connection` has not been properly opened. You should have a line like:

```
$connection = mysql_error($server, $user, $pass);
```

Also check [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to see the reason why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that cletus meant to suggest that you need to have a [`mysql_connect()`](http://us.php.net/mysql_connect) instead of `mysql_error()` before you attempt to perform a `mysql_query()`.  It will probably look like this (with the exception that 1and1 may have given you a specific hostname to connect to for your database which you should use in place of `localhost` below):

```
//Make sure this goes before any of your other mysql_* functions
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'yourUserName', 'yourPassword');
```

Passing `$connection` around for each of your queries isn't really necessary unless you have multiple database connections open concurrently that you are using and need to make sure to differentiate between the two when making query calls.  Otherwise, `mysql_query` assumes that you are using the last database that you connected to.

Also, for security purposes as mentioned by Frank you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` like so:

```
$q  = "SELECT * ";
$q .= "FROM " . DB_NAME . ".`blog` ";
$q .= "WHERE `blog`.`id` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($bId).";
```

Comment: I have updated my code with the `$connection` var. Also check the reply to Frank's comment. I do escape my code, just that I removed the call for the function when I posted it here.

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($q, $connection);` right before you run your query.  That should show you what each of the variables that you are passing into your mysql_query() actually are.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on my local system (via WAMP), I had no problems. At the time when I had problems, I was using 1&1 Hosting. 1&1 Hosting run PHP as CGI, which probably cause my problems. I couldnt handle allof the crap with 1&1 and switch to HostMonster. Now, I don't any issues. Plus, I rather use cPanel over 1&1's admin panel.